# Need satellite image for land classification

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, satellite

I am trying to develop a system(machine learning model) to identify whether the land is agricultural or paddy (dry land or wet-land) and has undergone changes over a period of time.

Can anyone suggest suitable dataset which I can use for training purposes?

Comment: Just in case for further questions regarding datasets, I highly encourage to join the Data Science exchange community https://datascience.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

after a few research i have got some datasets websites Please do check it:

https://data.world/datasets/land

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317914265_A_global_dataset_of_crowdsourced_land_cover_and_land_use_reference_data

https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/gdj3.32